# Multi Arm Bandit (MAB) -- Increasing reward function

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, online-algorithms

In the general stochastic MAB model, the reward obtained at each trial is generally assumed to be independent of previous trials and obtained from some fixed (but unknown) distribution.

However, if the reward function is a monotonically increasing function of time, what would be the corresponding MAB model? Should it be adversarial? It would be really helpful if you can point me to some resources (papers, books, articles) regarding this.